# Modify outer class property within anonymous class

Tags: java, api, rest, oop, arraylist

How do I go about populating my outer class's 'ArrayList' using an anonymous inner class method? Here's my code:

```
public class Bookshelf {

    private static final String TAG = "Bookshelf";
    private final ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public Bookshelf() {
        try {
            setContent();
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        Log.i(TAG, Integer.toString(books.size())); //outputs "0" (incorrect)
    }

    private void setContent() throws JSONException {
        RestClient.get("/books/", null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);

                for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        Book book = new Book();
                        book.setId(obj.getInt("_id"));
                        book.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));

                        books.add(book);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, Integer.toString(books.size())); //outputs 60 (correct)
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The API calls are working perfectly, and the 'ArrayList' is populated correctly within the inner class. However, trying to do anything with the 'ArrayList' outside of the inner class shows that it has gone back to empty. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: JsonHttpResponseHandler looks like a Guava future. If it is some sort of future, you probably need to block on it because there will be a race between the future completing and you checking the contents of the outer class.

Comment: If it's the android-async-http JsonHttpResponseHandler, you'll want to either map it to some flavor of future or have a `CountDownLatch` in `setContent` that you set in the callbacks, then `await` on before `setContent` returns.

Comment: try:
`books.add(new Book());`
`books.get(i).setId(obj.getInt("_id"));`
`books.get(i).setTitle(obj.getString("name"));`

Comment: @FallaCoulibaly thanks, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to put the part that is supposed to store the `books` in a helper method with the `JSONObject` as parameter and call it in your anonymous class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't completely understand the execution flow of your program.
It is not very clear what library you are using, but it seems that `RestClient.get()` is making an *asynchronous* request, which means that it does not wait for the response and does not block main thread execution. Usually, it is building some request object and submits its execution to another thread. That's why you need to provide your implementation of `JsonHttpResponseHandler` - it is responsible for handling the response whenever it is ready.
So your ArrayList hasn't "gone back to empty" it **is** empty at the time it is printed.
By the way, constructor isn't a good place for such logic. I'd move it to some separate service class, making it responsible for creation and populating the `Bookshelf` object.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks a bunch!